# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID

Tags: android

I don't know what error is this. It was working fine before, but it suddenly broke; I don't know why. Before I just change my icon and I already changed it back but it still error. Please help. if it's about the image I think not, because I use the image in login activity but it was fine

this is my java

```
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
            pinjamKelas();

            new daftarMahasiswa().execute();
        }
 public void pinjamKelas(){
        LinearLayout pinjamkelas = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pinjam_kelas);
        pinjamkelas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, KelasActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
class daftarMahasiswa extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Sedang menampilkan...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String link_url = "http://192.168.43.54/datapeminjamankelas/read_mahasiswa.php";
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = jParser.AmbilJson(link_url);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                str_json = json.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < str_json.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject ar = str_json.getJSONObject(i);
                    String nim = ar.getString("nim").trim();
                    String nama = ar.getString("nama").trim();
                    String ruang = ar.getString("ruang").trim();
                    HashMap map = new HashMap();
                    map.put(in_nim, nim);
                    map.put(in_nama, nama);
                    map.put(in_ruang, ruang);
                    data_map.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                    adapter = new RuangAdapter(MainActivity.this, data_map);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(list);

                    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()

                    {
                        @Override public void onItemClick (AdapterView < ? > parent, View view,
                                                           int position, long id){
                            String nim = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtNim)).getText().toString();
                            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailPinjamActivity.class);
                            i.putExtra("lemparNIM", nim);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

    public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null) return;
        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        int totalHeight = 0;
        View view = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
            if (i == 0)
                view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            view.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
```

this is my xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ecf0f1"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pinjam_kelas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/room" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pinjam Ruang kelas"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Kelas yang telah dipinjam:"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Peminjam"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Kelas"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Data Kosong"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my error

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.mqa.android.peminjamankelas, PID: 25294
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mqa.android.peminjamankelas/com.mqa.android.peminjamankelas.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070059
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2930)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1619)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6683)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070059
                      at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:209)
                      at android.content.res.MiuiResourcesImpl.getValue(MiuiResourcesImpl.java:91)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1329)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.createDrawableIfNeeded(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:234)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:755)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:87)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:128)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:54)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:31)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:31)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:198)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:70)
                      at com.mqa.android.peminjamankelas.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7046)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2930) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1619) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6683) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
```

Comment: Share your whole activity  and `pinjamKelas()` and `daftarMahasiswa` code with question

Comment: done @NileshRathod

Comment: please share your xml file

Comment: Please double check R.id.pinjam_kelas in the xml and R.id.txtNim

Comment: it's ok and match @Rinav

Comment: i already add it @masoudvali

Comment: Check other layour folders where you may have the same xml file with some id or widget missing.

Comment: also check your room drawable. is its name correct? if it's ok just clean your project and try rebuilding it

Comment: it works when i clean the project. Thanks! @masoudvali

Comment: ok. i just set it as an answer for other people. just approve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just clean your project and try rebuilding it.

Answer (score 2):

**Try This:**

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

it helps you

Comment: where should i add that?

Comment: add this line gradle properties

Comment: Can you elaborate the reason why AAPT2 has to be disabled? Does it have any known bug that causes this? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

1. did you add this res/xml/preference_headers.xml in resource directory?
2. Add android.enableAapt2=false to your gradle.properties file

Answer (score 0):

Just clean your project and rebuild it then run your project. it will work.. Happy Coding